# Debian - Video drivers installed but not activated

Tags: debian, drivers, graphics, amd-graphics

I just did a fresh install of Debian (Debian 10 - Buster). When I boot it up, the resolution is wrong and on **settings -> display** I've got only one option of resolution. I installed the corresponding drivers using this tutorial: https://wiki.debian.org/AtiHowTo

After rebooting quite a few times, the problem persisted. Then I checked the drivers with `find /sys | grep drivers.*08:00.0` and `find /dev -group video` and both give me an empty output. From there I concluded that the drivers are installed but not working, or activated at least. But after that I'm out of ideas. Thanks in advance.

Here are the characteristics of the CPU and GPU:

```
Architecture:        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
Address sizes:       43 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
CPU(s):              8
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-7
Thread(s) per core:  2
Core(s) per socket:  4
Socket(s):           1
NUMA node(s):        1
Vendor ID:           AuthenticAMD
CPU family:          23
Model:               24
Model name:          AMD Ryzen 5 3400G with Radeon Vega Graphics
Stepping:            1
CPU MHz:             1532.004
CPU max MHz:         3700.0000
CPU min MHz:         1400.0000
BogoMIPS:            7385.90
Virtualization:      AMD-V
L1d cache:           32K
L1i cache:           64K
L2 cache:            512K
L3 cache:            4096K
```

Comment: Try running `inxi -Gxx` which will display the driver that is loaded. Can you confirm that you are **not** using a separate Graphics card?

Comment: Linux doesn't seem to find the ```ìnxi -Gxx``` command and trying to install it with ```apt``` doesn't seem to help either. 
Yes, I can confirm I only have the integrated graphic card of the CPU.

Comment: That's surprising, since Debian include it in their **man pages** https://manpages.debian.org/buster/inxi/inxi.1.en.html

Comment: It seems I had my ```sources.list``` badly configured. I fixed that and updated the repos list and finally could install ```inxi```. I ran it and on the driver part said: ```driver: N/A```. So I guess that confirms my suspicion.